# Use OpenLayers 6 API without using Angular/Node frameworks

Tags: angular, jsp, model-view-controller, openlayers, struts

I have an application which runs on **OpenLayers2** for creating GIS inside JSP pages.

The application is in **Struts** framework.

I wish to upgrade that application to **OpenLayers6** for availing its new features.

Can I use **OpenLayers6** without using **Angular** framework?

Comment: Openlayers 6 has nothing to do with angular, so yes you can